# Line-Rectangle Collision Detection and Response

Tags: collision-detection

I've looked through Google and none of the solutions seem to pinpoint my idea. Ultimately, I want to create a level editor where I can draw lines and have them exported to a file for my engine to read. I'm having trouble getting path-rectangle to work. I'm using this in the context of a platformer, so I'm also interested in knowing which direction and distance the collision came from so I can resolve it. Which is the best algorithm for doing this? I'm only concerned about axis aligned rectangles.

EDIT: My character is represented as a rectangle and the level is represented by lines. The tools really do not matter as I'm looking for the mathematics behind it, not necessarily an implementation.

Comment: I think you're asking about line-rectangle collision. Is your game character in the shape of a rectangle, and the level is made of lines? Further explain what you're trying to do. What tools are you using? C++ or XNA or ActionScript or...?

Comment: @Olhovsky - edited.

Comment: Sigh, if you want your question answered, then just play along and answer my questions about your question -- it really does make things easier, even if it doesn't seem relevant to you right now. Anyways, I've started an answer for you below.

Comment: @Jopo tools are not irrelevant because they provide a common ground for which to communicate the idea, and since many libraries (e.g. XNA) provide tools to do this intersection test for you. Unless of course, your preferred language to communicate in is pure math with latex. Anyways, see if my answer below helps or not. Let me know :)

Comment: @Olhovsky - I am using XNA. I originally did not want to say this because I did not want to deter anyone from answering my question simply because of my technology choice. As an off-topic, I was reading your blog and wish you best of luck on your DBP project! It looks quite good so far.

Comment: XNA does have built in collision stuff for this, but since everything you have is axis aligned, it would just be better to use the code snippet I wrote below. And thanks!

Comment: And in that case, I changed my code snippet to be C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a simple way to test the intersection of a line segment against a rectangle is to do a line segment test against each line segment that the rectangle is made of.

However for axis aligned boxes we can do things more efficiently.

Here is the easiest to understand code that I could find:

http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/309

There are slightly more efficient ways, but that should suit you fine.

There are dozens of implementations of this all over the internet. Search for "line AABB intersection".

However, you say that your box is an axis aligned box (AABB), so does this mean that your lines are also axis aligned?

In that case, all you really need to test is whether each of the Y values of the four points of the AABB are above or below the Y value defined by your line, and whether each of those point's X values are within the X values defined by the segment ends of the line.

As I said in the comment on your question, explain to us what you're trying to do, because as it stands your question doesn't make very much sense.

If you're trying to make a game where you have lines that are not axis aligned, but the player *is* axis aligned, i.e., you have a box player that has only one corner of the box touching the lines, then my advice is to not make that game.

If you want to make a game where the box is lined up with the line, then my answer needs to change because then you want to know about OBB vs line intersection instead.

If you want to make a game where the lines of the level are axis aligned, then you don't need to test the player box against the level lines, you only need to test the box points agains the level line segments.

---

For axis aligned level lines vs AABB player:

[image: Player position and bounding box diagram.]

Each line segment of your level is made up of a Y value (the height of the line on the screen) and two X values (the left and right extents of the line). A line is a struct/class that stores X1, X2, Y.

Your AABB player is represented by two points, bottom left and top right (call them bottom_left and top_right).

C# code:

```
bool test_line_intersection(Line line, Vector2 bottom_left, 
        Vector2 top_right, out float intersect_amount){
    intersect_amount = 0;

    if(top_right.X < line.X1){
        // player is not intersecting line.
        return false;
    }

    if(bottom_left.X > line.X2){
        // player is not intersecting line.
        return false;
    }

    if(bottom_left.Y < line.Y && top_right.Y > line.Y){
        // bottom of player is below line 0, and player is intersecting line
        intersect_amount = line.Y - bottom_left.Y;
        return true;
    }

    // player is not intersecting line.
    return false;
}
```

If this function returns true then there is an intersection. In that case, add intersect_amount to the player position, and the player will no longer be intersecting with the line.

Comment: Sorry, I understand your confusion in my situation. My character is axis-aligned. My level is made up of straight, axis-aligned lines that are scattered throughout the level. I believe this is the last situation you have presented.

Comment: Okay, let me edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Jopo: I added some code for you which does the intersection test that you want. I just wrote that off the top of my head, so hopefully I didn't make any mistakes, and you get the idea :)

Comment: Edited answer to correct a mistake in my code.

Comment: Added the intersect_amount to the code, so that you can just add that value to your player position to correct collisions. (The value will be negative when the player is intersecting a line from below, or positive when the player is on top of the line, intersecting it.)

Comment: Quick question as I was implementing this: `if(bottom_right.X < line.X1){` is suppose to be `if(bottom_left.X < line.X1){`, correct?

Comment: No. Well, it depends how you want your game to behave. If the box is halfway on a line on the left side, do you want the player to be able to balance on the edge of the line? I assume yes, so it should be that if the right side of the box is to the left of the left side of the line, then the player is not intersecting.

Comment: In other words, if the right side of the box is to the right of the left side of the line, then the player *is* intersecting the line. If you do it your way, then the player will fall through the line when the left side of the player moves even a little bit to the left of the line, even though most of the box is still on the line.

Comment: @Ohlovsky - Okay, I was just confused as that was not one of the parameters passed in.

Comment: Jopo: Oh, sorry, I misread your question. It's actually supposed to be `if(top_right.X < line.X1){`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Maybe I've forgotten the XNA coordinate system - I changed the method header to this: `        bool test_line_intersection(Vector2 line1, Vector2 line2, Vector2 bottom_left,
        Vector2 top_right, out float intersect_amount)` as Line does not exist so I used vectors instead. I called these currently magic values: `intersect = test_line_intersection(a1, a2, new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(50, 50), out intersect1);` using a 50 by 50 pixel on a line and it detected no collision.

Comment: Well, you're now passing in 4 line values, but I only use 3, because you only need 3 for axis aligned lines. Define a line struct, `public struct AxisLine{ public float X1; public float X2; public float Y; }`.

Comment: (You only need 3 values for an axis aligned line because both points on the line share the same Y value).

Comment: Okay, I've implemented the AxisLine struct and replaced my current line drawing code to support it. No collision is detected, so I'm sure it's because of the parameters I have passed. I'm passing in `intersect = test_line_intersection(al1, new Vector2(0, 50), new Vector2(50, 50), out intersect1);` where intersect is a bool, al1 is an AxisLine, and the Vector2 values correspond to a 50 by 50 square.

Comment: What are the values in al1?

Comment: `al1.X1 = 360;
            al1.X2 = 560;
            al1.Y = 370;` and my 50x50 block = `new Vector2(500, 325)`, which means the bottom of the block touches the line by a bit.

Comment: A block is defined by two points (the bottom left point of the block and the top right point), not just one point. The two points that you passed into the function above do not intersect with that line.

Comment: One way to fix your issue: Create a Hero class that stores your hero's position and the top_right and bottom_left of the hero's box. Then have a method in the hero class `SetPosition(Vector2 pos)` that sets the correct top_right and bottom_left of the box when you change the hero position.

Comment: Sorry? I passed in al1, new Vector2(0,50), new Vector2(50, 0) into the function. Does that not constitute two points? I tried adding the blocks position into the mix for world coordinates, but that did not work either. The 500, 325 is the position of my block.

Comment: Another option to fix your issue: Only store the hero position, and change the method I gave you in this answer to take hero position and half the hero box width. Then you can compute the intersection using the position + half_width in this method instead.

Comment: (Vector2(0,0), Vector2(50,50)) represents a 50x50 box whose top left corner is at position (0,0) on the screen.

Comment: (Vector2(500+0, 325+0), Vector2(500+50,325+50)) represents a 50x50 box whose *top left corner* is at position (500,325) on the screen.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that in XNA the top left corner of the screen is (0,0). I might have an error somewhere due to that because I was thinking of (0,0) as the bottom left corner (or center). Anyways the issue so far is that you're passing the wrong parameters into the method because your box coordinates are not formed correctly :)

Comment: @Olhovsky - Okay, thanks! I'll use some paper and pencil later to figure it out! Gotta go to bed now, so it'll be tomorrow.

Comment: @Olhvosky - I'm still having trouble getting in the correct values. I've added the coordinates of the first line to the bottom left and top right values to put it into correct screen coordinates, but it still isn't working. Do you have any ideas of one parameters I must pass?

Comment: You dont add the coordinates of the line to bottom_left and top_right. bottom_left and top_right are supposed to be two corners of the box around your player. If your hero is at the center of the box, then: `bottom_left = (hero.X - box_width/2, hero.Y - box_height/2)`, `top_right = (hero.X + box_width/2, hero.Y + box_height/2)`.

Comment: I added a diagram to the answer to make the situation clearer.

Comment: @Olhovsky - Oh, I see what you mean. I'll try and transfer these numbers to include the fact the origin is at the top left. Thanks for the diagram!

Comment: @Olhovsky - If the origin is at the top left, wouldn't the parameters be `bottom_left = new Vector2(heroPos.X, heroPos.Y + 50);
            top_right = new Vector2(heroPos.X + 50, heroPos.Y);`, assuming a 50 by 50 block?

Comment: @Jopo: Yes. Except it should be `+25` not `+50` assuming the box width is 50. Everything I've written has been for the origin at (0,0). You might have to flip the `<` and `>` in part of the method I wrote in the answer for the XNA coordinate system.

Comment: @Olhovsky - Correct me if I'm wrong, but if 0,0 was at the top left, and thus heroPos is oriented at the top left, would the top-right not be it's X position + the width of the character (50)?

Comment: @Jopo: Yes you are right if you want to represent the hero's position as the top left of the box. Like in the diagram, if your hero position is the center of the box, then you need to add half the width to get to the top_right X, and subtract half the width to get to the bottom_left X. If the screen origin (0,0) is at the top left then you need to subtract half the width to get to the top_right Y (because smaller values are closer to the top of the screen). What I wrote about the X values a few posts back is still correct in the XNA coordinate system.

Comment: @Olhovksy- So if it still does not work, what would that mean?

Comment: Jopo: First, test the function on values that you know should work. Tell me a line, a bottom_left and a top_right that you are giving to the function, where you think the function should be telling you that the hero box and line intersect.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't give up on this :) Remember that my function assumes that positive Y is up, but in XNA spritebatch screen coordinates, positive Y is down. So the function needs to be modified slightly. If you tell me a function input that doesn't work for you, I can confirm whether you're using the function correctly, and possibly help you fix the function to work in your coordinate system :)

Comment: @Olhovsky- Don't worry, I think this is pretty important. :D Unfortunately, school has gotten in the way, but it's the weekend. I'll try switching the signs for the Y on the function soon. Thanks for your continued support!

Comment: @Olhovsky - I do believe I got it to work! I switched the < and > signs in the function and double checked my inputs, and they seem to resolve correctly! I do need to more checking though. I'm just wondering, since my box doesn't move yet, does this function give the direction it came from? Right now it is giving me negative values that I can bump my heroPos.Y by and the collision is resolved, though it often isn't the shortest one.

Comment: @Olhovsky- Okay, I implemented movement and I can confirm that collision detection works (thanks!) but it doesn't tell direction. Despite if I approach the line from the top or bottom, it always gives a negative number. If I approach it from the top, I get -1, etc, which is correct. If I approach it from the bottom, I get -49, which can also resolve collisions but is from the wrong direction.

Comment: Paste your function here: http://pastebin.com/ and link it to me.

Comment: @Olhovsky- http://pastebin.com/X7nP5NDi

Comment: Oh I see. Well, the function currently returns how much intersection there is, but it has no way of knowing whether the line is "above" or "below" you. It just "sees" a line and a box and tells you right at this moment, how much it is intersecting. So what you can do to fix this, is have two fields in your hero class (or however you store your hero), one for the current position (`Vector2 position`) and one for the previous position (`Vector2 lastPosition`). Then after you use this function for the intersection test, check if `position.Y - lastPosition.Y` is negative.

Comment: if `position.Y - lastPosition.Y` is negative, then your hero is moving up, so you should add whatever test_line_intersection returned, if not the you should subtract whatever test_line_intersection returned. This will do the collision response properly. Hopefully I got the signs right :)

Comment: @Olhovsky - Got it! Your calculations were basically spot on, but since if I approached from the bottom of the line, the function would return something like -40 instead of 10 (the difference being that -40 is if it would of came from the top and the 10 comes from the collision coming from the bottom), I added the texture's width. I have another question though - if I come from the sides, the box will be pushed up quickly to either the top or bottom of the line. I actually don't want this behaviour - in a platformer, I'd rather have it not to push.

Comment: @Olhovsky- I've done some more testing, and it only seems like this happens when I move onto the line sideways, then press up or down. If I don't press either of those keys, it won't pop me back up.

Comment: For this you might want to start a new question. Basically you currently output the Y intersection amount. You now want to also output the X intersection amount. You'll also need to keep track of the amount of intersection on X and Y at the previous update, in order to know which direction to push the block out of the line.

Comment: @Olhovsky - Okay, thanks! I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted as that is _long_ overdue! I'd like to thank you for your continued support and thorough answers, as well as the patience and encouragement you have given me. A stunning amount of comments later, I've reached quite a good point in my platformer - I'm working on a simple level editor to draw lines and have the prototype read them in. Once again, one final thank you for all the help! Good luck on your endeavours!

Comment: I'm glad your game is coming along Jopo, good luck :)

Comment: @Olhovsky - Just realized I didn't mark it as the answer! Sorry, marked it ;) Thank you!